# Why do you need a separate product_to_category database table?

Tags: opencart

I've been looking at the Opencart database structure and basically, they have a product table, a category table, and then a table with 2 columns which links a product_id to a category_id.

What is the reasoning behind this? Would it not make things simpler to just include the category_id as a column in the product table?

Comment: Think out of the box. A product can not only have 1 category... What if say you have a device that is an electric screwdriver and a drill too, and would like to have the same product under both categories - that are obviously not in the same subtree? So this is just because of the many-to-many relationship between product and category entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a product can belong to more than one category and signifies a many-to-many relationship. It is part of the normalization process.